# REACT NATİVE Image Pipeline was not initialized

Tags: react-native

Here is the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i70By.png)

I couldn't find anything on the topic, and I am expecting no error.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.